# I am trying to populate drop boxes

Tags: vb.net, drop-down-menu

Here is what I have so far to populate a couple drop down boxes in visual basic.

I may need global variables but I am not sure how to do that. I have been told to use `Dim` and the variable names of the drop boxes but I keep getting errors saying they are already friends within the form.

*This is a homework assignment, however I am not asking you to do the assignment but simply asking help with the problem I am having within the drop boxes. I don't expect you wonderful people to earn my grades for me! Thank you for any help!

```
Public Class Form1
    '// Mortgage Calculator Assignment 1.
    '// Can calculate payments on a given loan at a given rate for a given term.
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    End Sub
    '// Inputs rate starting at 3.25% through 6.75% at steps of 0.25% into the drop down box.
    Private Sub cbRate_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cbRate.SelectedIndexChanged
        For i As Decimal = 3.25 To 6.75 Step 0.25
            cbRate.Items.Add(i & "%")
        Next
    End Sub
    '// Inputs term in years from 10 through 40 at steps of 5 year intervals into the drop down box.
    Private Sub cbTerm_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cbTerm.SelectedIndexChanged
        For i As Integer = 10 To 40 Step 5
            cbTerm.Items.Add(i)
        Next
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: So, you have code for what to do when the selection changes, for `cbRate` and `cbTerm`. Are you saying how do you add items in the first place? What is the precise error you get when you try using `dim`?

Comment: If I declare cbRate globally such as Dim cbRate As Decimal I get the following "Error 1 'cbRate' is already declared as 'Friend WithEvents cbRate As System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox' in this class."

Comment: Yes and no, I'm not entirely sure which example was shown that used DIm to declare global variables. That's why I am asking if this code would need global variables to utilize the process of populating the drop down menues.

Comment: So you already have the combo boxes (not decimals, note). So, just add the items on the form load. Global variables are always evil.

Comment: He wants us to use the code I have above using the step method. I watched him do it but I've apparently missed a step somewhere. He told us we could just enter them manually but wants us to use both methods.

Comment: Have you got a from with combo boxes on?

Comment: Oops I read that before I looked at the code. I didn't have the code within the entire form like you have shown below. I moved things into the form...seems to help lol. Geeze I donno what I was thinking. Wish I would have realized that before I posted my blunders to the world!

Comment: It might help if you knew what language you're working in. VBA != VB.Net.

Comment: It's true, i guess thats why they call this process learning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need global variables.

Try just populating the combo boxes in the form load:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
   '// Inputs rate starting at 3.25% through 6.75% at steps of 0.25%
   ' into the drop down          
    For i As Decimal = 3.25 To 6.75 Step 0.25
        cbRate.Items.Add(i & "%")
    Next

    '// Inputs term in years from 10 through 40 at steps of 5 year intervals
    ' into the drop down box.
    For i As Integer = 10 To 40 Step 5
        cbTerm.Items.Add(i)
    Next
End Sub
```

Edit: the combo boxes were declared (probably) for you when you added them to the form in the designer.